# Vb.net Add all Declared Buttons to my form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to add all declared buttons into my form

something like:

```
dim btn1,btn2,btn3 as new button

for each btn as button in declared.buttons
me.controls.add(btn)
next
```

Comment: NO! you have to add it *manually* (one by one).

Comment: Why don't you add them to a collection like `List(Of Button)` first? Then you can loop them and do whatever you want to do with them.

Comment: And how do you expect to lay them out?  150 buttons all separately declared? I'm gonna take a **guess** there's going to be a better way to do what you're trying to acoomplish

Comment: @none 150 buttons? Then you’re doing it wrong. Are you maybe abusing buttons to create interactive graphics? Buttons aren’t really suitable here. And otherwise 150 buttons will simply kill the user interface.

Comment: i just want to try new thing, without using List , just add all declared buttons into my form, I'm not lazy. i just want to know if there is a way to add all declared buttons into my form.

Comment: If you just create them as you have above, and without a list, you'd have to use reflection to get all fields from your form.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the buttons like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 150
    Dim btn As New Button()
    btn.Name = "btn" + i.ToString()
    Controls.Add(btn)
Next
```

Later, you can access the buttons like this:

```
Dim btn As Button = CType(Controls("btn1"), Button)
```

However, if you are needing to load that many controls dynamically, you may want to reconsider your design.  It smells like a bad idea for most situations.

Comment: I already know about it, i want to know if i can add all declared buttons into my form in my way. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Ok.  The only way you can do that is with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your buttons you've declared using something like this:

```
Dim buttons = From fi In Me.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
   Where fi.FieldType Is GetType(Button)
   Select CType(fi.GetValue(Me), Button)
```

Off the top of my head.. Still working on it.. but You get the idea?